# Add character to beginning and end of php line

Tags: php

Please tell me, I transmit the following text using textarea post php:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

I accept the text with lines like this - `echo nl2br($_POST['list']);` The question is how to add characters to the beginning and end of each line so that the text turns out like this:

```
(Text1)
(Text2)
(Text3)
```

Comment: Split by new line, add `()`, then join again.

Comment: @u_mulder Show by example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is with a `foreach` :

```
$data = nl2br($textarea); // add '<br />' after each newline
$data_array = explode('<br />', $data);

foreach ($data_array as $data_str) {
    echo '(' . trim($data_str) . ')<br />';
}
```

Comment: Here's the output (space at the beginning of the second line)
`(Text1)
( Text2)
( Text3)`

Comment: Try with `trim($data_str)` to avoid space maybe ?

Comment: This is used in the answer.

Comment: Yes I just edited my answer. If it doesn't works can you add edit your question with the output of `var_dump(nl2br($_POST['list']))` please ?